# Objective c -enumaeratorAtPath: Not Working at root level folders

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

I am trying to enumerate files and folders at root level

```
 (/Users/Myname/Desktop or /Users/Myname/Documents),[enumarator nextobject] always gives nil value.
```

How can i solve this issue.

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator* enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:@"/Users/Myname/Desktop"];

NSString *content=  [enumerator nextObject];//content always nil.
```

Comment: You should not enter the document path as literal, but use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AminNegm-Awad. I tried both, but its not working, I have a doubt that is sandbox  making this problems .

Comment: Yes, the sandbox makes that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSDirectoryEnumerator * emuerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:@"/usr/Myname/Desktop"]; 
 NSString *filename; while ((filename = [emuerator 
 nextObject])) 
   {
    NSLog (@"file!  %@", filename); 
   }
```

OR

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSFileManager *manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *emuerator= [manager enumeratorAtPath: @"/usr/Myname/Desktop"];


for (NSString *filename in emuerator) {
    // Do something with file
}

[manager release];
```